# How to convert General value to Date format

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

How to change the format of the column in excel using PowerShell?

I have a script that converts CSV to .xlsx and it's working perfectly,
but I have one column with dates ("General" format cell) but I need "Date" format cell.

I tried everything, eg. `[datetime]::ParseExact, $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"`, etc.

Probably I should add something here:

```
$convertedDate = Get-Date ($commitime+"-"+$commitDate+"-"+$commitYearToGet)
```

EDIT:

```
$FileNameCSV = "$env:WORKSPACE/masterdata.csv"
$FileNameExcel = "\\masterdata$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).xlsx"


$DLLPath = "D:\EPPlus.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DLLPath) | Out-Null


$Format = New-object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat
$Format.Delimiter = ","

$Format.TextQualifier = '"'
$Format.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$Format.SkipLinesBeginning = '0'
$Format.SkipLinesEnd = '1'

$TableStyle = [OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles]::Medium1

$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage 
$Worksheet = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("CM")

$null=$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText((Get-Item    $FileNameCSV),$Format,$TableStyle,$true) 

#$null=$Worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText($file,$format) 


$Worksheet.Cells[$Worksheet.Dimension.Address+1].AutoFitColumns()

$ExcelPackage.SaveAs($FileNameExcel)
```

Comment: How do you convert you csv ? Are you using the Excel's COM ? If so simply set the cell's format before you write the value.. something like Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: Cells in Excel spreadsheets have a *value* and a *format*. The format defines how Excel displays the value. To answer your question you need to show us the value, the format, and how you actually want the value displayed.

Comment: ...I've tried `$Worksheet.Cells.Item(2,3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` and `.DateFormat` but Jenkins return fails like: `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException`

Comment: I using EPPlus.dll. My csv file: 
"David Booth ","27-Feb-2014","2","1"
I want have format like dd/mm/yyyy and "Date" Cells Format.
Sorry for double post, but I can't edit post.

Comment: I think problem is resolved. I added `$Worksheet.Column(3).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";` and now it's working! I have `Date` value, but still with format like: `27-Feb-2014` and I don't know how convert to `dd/mm/yyyy` format.